# How can I set Required Field by Conditions on fields in odoo11?

Tags: python, odoo-11

```
owner_user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Assignee')
project_name = fields.Char('Project Name')
project_manager = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Project Manager',index=True, track_visibility='always')
remarks = fields.Char('Remarks', size=100)
```

I need in my view for perticular assignee if I enter project name in field project manager should be mandatory.If Project name is not entered for that assignee remarks should be mandatory?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in xml like this for project manager and same for others fields in its view.This attrs works fine in it

Comment: <field name="project_manager" attrs={'required':[('project_name','!=',False)]}